# Joomla articles showing up as PDFs in Google search results

Tags: joomla1.5

I have certain articles which i do not want Google to index .I have set the settings to noindex nofollow in the metadata settings in the backend for the article .However now even though the article itself does not show up a pdf version of it does .

Any thoughts on how to prevent them from being indexed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tow choices:

disable pdf button going to  articles -> configuration button and look for the PDF option button.

change the .htaccess file located at the root folder of your Joomla Installation dir and add the following lines:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /index.php?view=article*&format=pdf 
Disallow: /index.php?view=article*&print=1*
Disallow: /index.php?option=com_mailto*
Disallow: /component/mailto/* 

User-agent: Slurp
Disallow: /index.php?view=article*&format=pdf 
Disallow: /index.php?view=article*&print=1*
Disallow: /index.php?option=com_mailto*
Disallow: /component/mailto/*
```

width one of these options you must solve the problem, the latter also get rid of duplicate content from the send to friend option and print view.

Also bear in mind that it will take some time to change the way Google or other bots are indexing your site.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Depends where the pdf files are stored.  You can use the [robots.txt file](http://www.robotstxt.org/) to exclude the folder where the pdf files are located.  You could also add `rel="nofollow"` to the links to the PDF files.

Some links for reading:

- http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20030728_spidering.html
- http://www.webmasterworld.com/robots_txt/3741109.htm

Comment: But i do no have any pdfs the article itself is appearing as a pdf in the search results . I see this happening when i search in Bing

Comment: Can you post a link to one of those search results in bing?

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=erin+hoesly+thomson+reuters+resources&go=&qs=n&sk=&form=QBLH

Comment: None of those results return a PDF, sorry not sure what you're talking about